# Can you use Python for both front end and back end using Django framework?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, frontend, backend

I'm watching the udemy Django tutorial that requires using JavaScript as the front-end and Python for the back-end:

- Can you replace JavaScript with Python?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, python can't be used in frontend.

You need frontend technologies like `html`, `css`, `javascript`, `jQuery` etc...
for frontend.

Python can be used as scripting language in backend.

Comment: I think you could create a module that generates html  and css code using specific functions. It wouldn't the most efficient way but it would be helpful to generate default pages.

Comment: In GWT you don’t use much HTML and JS... that is nice

Answer (score 5):

As others already said, basically you can't use Python at the front-end. You can use [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/) or something like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) in your templates, but generally speaking these engines run on your **server**, not in the browser.

Actually, you **can** use Python to write the code, that runs in the browser, using [transpilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) like [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org). But I don't recommend you to do such a thing on a real project because of raising complexity and difference between these two languages. The only advantage would be that you can use one language to write both front-end and back-end. But the complexity of supporting this code will not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Its true that you can do something interesting with Django template system. but like @Astik said you cant replace javascript in front end. Personally I don't use javascript for some Django projects because I don't need it, but there are many situation that I have to. However that depends about your project is going to work.

Something better than Django templates system is [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/faq/#how-compatible-is-jinja2-with-django) read more about it maybe help you